What is the purpose and typical use cases of optimisticData in Apollo Client's InMemoryCache
I'm trying to understand the purpose and best use cases of optimisticData in Apollo Client's InMemoryCache. I understand that it relates to optimistic updates, but I'm not entirely clear on how it functions alongside data and in what scenarios it is most useful.
Questions:

How does optimisticData interact with data in InMemoryCache?

What are some practical examples or use cases for utilizing optimisticData effectively in Apollo Client?


I'm looking for guidance on when and why to use optimisticData, along with some example scenarios to help clarify its role in the caching system.
I've tried digging into the source code and running tests related to src/__tests__/refetchQueries.ts. Specifically, I experimented with setting refetchQueries's optimistic flag to true and false. However, when I use cache.extract, both optimisticData and data appear the same, and I can't see a clear distinction between them. Any insights into why this might be happening or how optimisticData is expected to differ in this context would be greatly appreciated.
